# Non-standard "because" usage - is it valid?

Tags: grammaticality

I've currently reading Neal Stephenson's book "The System of the World", and there have been multiple instances of him using a sentence structure with "because" that seems strange.

As an example, one sentence of the form in question is:

> Jack was silent for a while, because alert.

I would normally expect to see this written something like:

> Jack was silent for a while, because he was alert.

That is, he seems to omit repeating the subject. Is this structure valid? I read quite a bit, but can't recall ever seeing anyone else do this.

*Editing to add another example of this structure, which I believe is now the third or fourth time I've seen it in this book:*

> Upon entering the Chapel, every denizen of Newgate stops in his tracks for a few moments because staggered by a blast of light, a sort of optical fanfare.

Comment: The context, with censorship: "There were bonfires, fist-fights, and dogs sniffing each other in Charing Cross, and Jack was silent for a while, because alert. But Roger's Jack, Daniel, and Isaac..." I still don't understand why Stephenson did that sentence. Haven't read this book but I've read others and I've seen nothing like that.

Comment: Both of these passages work even better when *because* is elided in favor of a comma, though it would leave the causal connection implied at best; is that true in all such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically incorrect, because the clause has no subject. Of course it is not essential to always be strictly grammatically correct. People often violate the rules for effect. The problem is when someone violates the rules for no apparent reason.

In this case I don't see how it achieves any useful effect, but I'm just looking at one sentence out of context.

I can't think of any other examples of this sort of construction off the top of my head, other than from people who where obviously struggling with the language.

Comment: It’s funny. You can say *Jack was silent for a while, and alert* or *Jack was horizontal for a while, but alert* or even *Jack was silent for a while, and thus alert.* I’m not sure what it is about *because* that makes it so powerfully wrong here (and it definitely offends my ears too).

Comment: Of course it's grammatically correct. As Barrie says, we use ellipsis a great deal in conversation. I agree that this example is awkward, but it is certainly not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Colin: To say "people do this frequently" and "this is correct" are not the same thing. Some rules are arbitrary and can only be defined by common usage -- like the definition of a word. But other rules are based on logical consistency. Having no subject in a clause is a logical inconsistency.

Comment: @Jason: Hmm, I don't think "Jack was silent for a while, and alert" is grammatically correct. "Jack was silent and alert for a while" would certainly be correct. But you can't just rearrange words in a sentence without changing meaning.

Comment: @Jay That’s surprising to me. What did you think about *silent for a while, but alert*? And what do you think about these examples? 1. *I sleep only with difficulty; it is cold at night, and damp.* 2. *I am angry at men, and mistrustful.* Both come from [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). They strike me as impeccable.

Comment: @Jay I don't see that as a clause with no subject. I see *silent for a while, and alert* as an coordination of adjective phrases, joined by *and*, functioning as predicate nominative. The comma is only there to help the reader parse it.

Comment: @Jay. We're talking language here, not logic. Often they coincide, sometimes they don't. If a structure is commonly used by native speakers of a language, then it is grammatical (at least in some dialect or register). Neither logic nor authority has anything to do with the question. (I accept that there can be evidential question of what constitutes "commonly")

Comment: @Colin: We're off on a tangent, but: If everyone agrees that a word means a certain thing, then that's what it means. It's pointless to say that it "really" means something else because some authority said so or whatever. But grammar rules -- at least some grammar rules -- carry some logic and consistency. "Behind the wall" is not a complete sentence, not because of any convention, but because it does not have a subject. It may be effective in context. But it doesn't matter how often people say it, it's still not a complete sentence.

Comment: @Jay: Agreed, it is not a complete sentence: it is an elliptic one. That doesn't mean that it is "wrong" or "ungrammatical" - it's just not a full sentence. In some kinds of writing it would not be acceptable as a sentence, but that is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: @Colin: Well, I don't want to get into a debate, so unless you go off on a different tangent here's my last comment: If it is not a complete sentence, than it is not grammatically correct. Period. If by "wrong" you mean "you shouldn't do it", then no, being grammatically incorrect is not necessarily "wrong". I often write things that are grammatically incorrect for effect. Like just above I wrote "Period.", which is clearly not a complete sentence. It's okay to break the general rules when you have a good reason. It's not okay to break the rules because you don't know any better.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of ellipsis, the omission of a word or words from a sentence. We use it all the time in conversation. There is nothing ungrammatical in your example, but the extent to which it might be effective in a novel (which I take ‘The System of the World’ to be) more properly falls under the heading of literary criticism.

Comment: Are there not patterns of ellipsis which are standard and others which are not?  This example certainly offends my ears.

Comment: @z7sg - I don't remember the passage, but Jack is a C16th century pirate so Stephenson might be trying to make him sound authentic.

Comment: Aural offence is not a sound basis for grammatical analysis. Some forms of ellipsis can lead to ambiguity, as in 'John likes Mary more than Peter' and these are best avoided. That apart, I'm afraid I can't provide any relevant generalisation.

Comment: I think this is ellipsis taken too far. I had to re-read the sentence a couple of times, and even after reading the suggested expansion, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around its meaning. So in the sense that it fails to get its meaning across effectively, it's not a valid construction.

Comment: @Martin: this isn't a spoken line, so that wouldn't be the intent of it. As I mentioned, he's used an identical structure multiple times in the book, and it's bothered me every time it's appeared. I'll see if I can find another instance of it from the book to edit into my question.