# Use of "because of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, conjunctions

In  high school, the teacher told me that *because* is used to answer “why” question, as below:

> - Why <strike>you</strike> are you using my shoes?
> - I am using your shoes because I like them.

However, the use of *of* after *because* looks like it changes the meaning to something completely different:

> The sun hid its light because of the eclipse

How can I distinguish where I should use just a plain *because* without any *of* following it from where I should use the full *because of* phrase?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7385/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/78985/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/44412/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34396/2085

Comment: @tchrist I don't believe any of these answers manix' question.

Comment: @StoneyB Don’t worry, I didn’t say they were the answers.  I just said they were related. If I thought they answered the question, I would have closevoted as a dup, which I did not.

Comment: @tchrist, all of them were useful :)

Comment: I hope your teacher also told you that the question should be "Why are you using my shoes?".

Comment: @DJClayworth, probably he did, but as you note: english is not my native language and I'm in a learning process :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Because* is a conjunction, and introduces a subordinate clause giving an explanation of what is expressed in the main clause. *Because of* means ‘by reason of, on account of’ and is followed by a noun phrase.

Comment: Really clear, Thank you! A single word can make a considerable difference in the meaning.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a point of grammar, not usage.

*Because* is a subordinating conjunction that can introduce an entire tensed subordinate clause (such clauses must contain at least a subject and a tensed verb). **But** it can also introduce just a noun phrase, instead of a whole clause.

When *because* introduces a noun phrase -- and not a clause -- the conjunction *because* adds the preposition *of*, to become the complex preposition *because of*. It's that simple.

- *He left because we asked her to.*
- *He left because **of** our request.*
- *Because she intended to see us, she stayed until the end.*
- *Because **of** her intention, she stayed until the end.*

Note that embedded questions and other types of clauses are considered noun phrases:

- *He left because **of** what we said to her.*
- *He left because **of** her getting so upset.*